# How can i implement ListMode to use for my list show all file in directory?

Tags: java, swing

I am newbie in Swing library. My program have a JFileChooser for choose a directory.  And I will show all file in this directory by JList in a JScrollpane but when when i choose new directory, my list do not update itself.I found on internet and they said bescause of ListMode .Can you help me make FileListMode implement ListMode ?

Answer (score 0):

> I will show all file in this directory by JList in a JScrollpane

Then you already know how to add data to a `ListModel`.

> but when when i choose new directory, my list do not update itself.

Create a new `ListModel` with the data and then add the model to the list:

```
DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();
// add data to the model
list.setModel( listModel );
```

The main point is DON'T create a new JList. Just replace the model of the JList with the new ListModel containing the new data.

Comment: when i do it with Jtree , i make a FileTreeModel implement TreeMode , it have a property File root and when root change , i setMode for my JTree . I try make a FileListMode implement ListMode but it's difficult @camickr

Comment: I don't know what you are saying. A JTree is used to show a tree structure.  So you show the directory and all its sub directories in tree structure. A JList is used to show only a single directory and all the files in that one directory. There is no need to create a custom ListModel! Update your question to clarify your requirement.